# Is my Graph Graceful?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, graph-theory

A [Graceful Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GracefulGraph.html) is a type of [Simple Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html).  Graceful graphs are special because there is a way to label all their nodes with positive integers so that when the edges are also labeled with the differences of the nodes they connect, no two edges have the same label and every label up to the number of edges is used.

### Worked Out Example

Here is a Simple graph that we suspect is a Graceful graph

[image: Simple Graph]

Let us try the following labeling:

[image: Labeled]

Note we are permitted to skip integers in our node labeling.  Now we label every edge with the positive difference between the nodes it connects.  For increased visibility I have labeled these in red.

[image: Doubly labeled]

Each edge has a unique number and no number between between 1 and 7 (the number of edges we have) is left out.  Thus our graph is graceful.

## Task

Given a graph, via any reasonable method of input, output a truthy value if it is graceful and a falsy value otherwise.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the objective is to minimize your byte count.

### Test Cases

Here graphs are represented as an array of edges:

```
3 nodes:

[(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)]

True

Labeling:

Node 0 -> 0
Node 1 -> 2
Node 2 -> 3
```

---

```
5 nodes:

[(0,1),(0,4),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]

False
```

---

```
5 nodes:

[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]

True

Labeling:

Node 0 -> 0
Node 1 -> 1
Node 2 -> 3
Node 3 -> 6
Node 4 -> 10
```

---

```
9 nodes

[(0,1),(1,2),(1,7),(1,8),(2,3),(2,6),(3,4),(4,5)]

True

Labeling:

Node 0 -> 0
Node 1 -> 1
Node 2 -> 3
Node 3 -> 6
Node 4 -> 10
Node 5 -> 15
Node 6 -> 11
Node 7 -> 7
Node 8 -> 8
```

---

```
5 nodes

[(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(3,4)]

False
```

Comment: I think algorithms to check gracefulness are only known for certain classes of graphs (e.g. [trees](http://www.jims-a.org/index.php/jimsa/article/viewFile/14/pdf_1))

Comment: @ngenisis It can certainly be brute forced.  There are more efficient algorithms for certain classes but you can use restraints on the edge sizes to create a maximum node label difference.

Comment: `[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]` is probably a noteworthy edge case.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, graphs of the form `{(k-1,k) : 0 < k < n}` require the highest labels of all graphs with the same number of nodes.

Comment: @Dennis Oh yes.  That is certainly true they should require `n(n+1)/2` as their highest label.  I have added your test case.

Comment: Can we take one-indexed nodes?

Comment: @Dennis I sure hope so

Comment: @Dennis Yes.  I/O Format is very flexible so the focus is on the algorithm rather than the pre and post processors.

Comment: I'm being fussy (or wrong) here, but you say positive integers at the start of the question and use 0 as a label later. Could you change that to say just integers?

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
FSŒ!ị@€ḅ-AċJ
```

Takes an array of edges as 1-indexed node pairs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@8WfHSS4sPd3Q6PmtY83NGq63ik2@v////RGoY6Rpo6GkY6xpqxAA) (Horrendously inefficient. Don't bother with the actual test cases.)

#### How it works

```
FSŒ!ị@€ḅ-AċJ  Main link. Argument: A (array of pairs)

FS            Flatten and sum, yielding s. This is an upper bound for the labels
              a graceful labeling (if one exists) would require.
  Œ!          Take all permutations of [1, ..., s].
      €       For each permutation P:
    ị@          Replace each integer in A with the element of P at that index.
       ḅ-     Convert all pairs from base -1 to integer, mapping (a,b) to b-a.
         A    Take absolute values.
           J  Yield the indices of A, i.e., [1, ..., len(A)].
          ċ   Count the occurrences of [1, ..., len(A)] in the result to the left.
```

Comment: `ḅ-` is one of my favorite Jelly tricks :-)

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <strike>121</strike> 116 bytes

*Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to JungHwan Min and Martin Ender*

```
Cases[Range[1+Tr[n=Range@Length[e=EdgeList@#]]]~Tuples~VertexCount@#,w_/;Sort[Abs[#-#2]&@@w[[List@@#]]&/@e]==n]!={}&
```

### Explanation

[image]

Pure function which takes a Mathematica `Graph` object with vertices `{1, 2, ..., k}` for some nonnegative integer `k`. In the worst case, we will only need vertex labels ranging from `1` to `1 + (1 + 2 + ... EdgeCount@#)`. Since it saves us some bytes later, we will let `e` be the list of edges and `n` be the list `{1, 2, ..., EdgeCount@#}`, so the vertex weights will be drawn from `Range[1+Tr[n=Range@Length[e=EdgeList@#]]]`. We generate a list of all `Tuples` of length `VertexCount@#`, then we choose the `Cases` which give graceful labelings and check to see that the result is `Unequal` to the empty list `{}`. Gracefulness of the list of vertex weights `w` is checked by `Map`ping the function `Abs[#-#2]&@@w[[List@@#]]&` over the list of edges `e`, `Sort`ing the result, and checking whether the result is `Equal` to `n`. Here is a breakdown of that function:

```
               List@@#     Replace the Head of the edge with List; i.e., UndirectedEdge[a,b] becomes {a,b}.
            w[[       ]]&  Select the corresponding vertex weights from the list w.
          @@               Replace the Head of that expression (List) with the function
Abs[#-#2]&                   which returns the absolute difference between its first two arguments.
                           This effectively passes the vertex weights into the absolute difference function.
```

Comment: save a byte by messing with some precedence: `VertexCount[#]`->`VertexCount@#`

Comment: Btw, the `Tr` trick for `Length` no longer saves bytes if you need to add parentheses. `Length[e=EdgeList@#]` is the same length. But it's shorter to avoid that altogether and rewrite the triangular number there as `Tr@Range@EdgeCount@#` (and then replace `e` at the end with `EdgeList@#`. Second, the function operator rarely saves bytes, in this case I think it's shorter to use `Cases` instead of `Select` and then `w_/;` instead of `w`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 449 bytes

```py
R=range
def f(g):
 q=[(v:={**{i:-1 for j in g for i in j},0:0},[],{*v}-{0})]
 while q:
  m,e,n=q.pop(0)
  if not n:
   if all(i in e for i in R(1,len(g)+1)):return m
   continue
  for i in n:
   if(k:=[N for j in g if i in j and m[(N:=j[j[1]!=i])]!=-1]):
    y=[m[N]for N in k]
    for o in{*R(min(y)+1,max(y)+len(g)+1)}-{*m.values()}:
     E=[abs(Y-o)for Y in y]
     if all(U not in e and U<=len(g)for U in E):q+=[({**m,i:o},e+E,n-{i})] 
    break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZE9b8IwEIZ3fsV1s8MFJUBbZNUjKwMSQ2VlSIsDhsQJIdCiKL@dnk1LkdpKXV6d7@Pxe3Z1atalHU2q@nyeyzq1K91b6gwytuKiBzup2FHINghaI8IYsrKGDRgLKx8aF246jETUoUqwDY5d2EYdT3rwtja5hh1BoECNVu4GVVmxiFPCZGDLBqwrukOa58yz9Dd2zmLMtSUf/ZhzUevmUFso3MRraRtjD5ria/sXi22FVLNbo8S/@ITULqFQbCbkRm1UnNxJk3DSME64H4eTVIWaJW565ma2iU@7c0nnNpizwlh2Ik9YpO8uuHqkzYNicEzzg94z3l2AMJUqfdmz57DkjvLsqKcL9WvzhX8Mv71zuHiSF6brX7j8lItdn36CvqFAI8oOdX@KNmwNvTR41kut0@25qo1tWMYUizDmSDokjUkTzns/q@PPKrIhjkhHlPmt8/89MT56nVz7h/jwOYVsjPd/OBneEEZex993nT8A)